# import CSV file, get monitor serial based csv data

Tags: powershell, monitor, serial-number, import-csv, export-csv

> I'm trying to figure out is there a way to read CSV file in Powershell
>   and  import in cell 1 column 1 the data -"machine name" to get the
>   monitor serial number ?

Right now I have this code in which I manually replace the machine name (Station01) with the monitor serial number and then I copy the serial number and paste it into the csv file.

I'm hoping the that Csv file can be used to record multiple monitors for each serial number on the columns. 
Example, 4 or 5 lines one for each machine containing the serial numbers 2 or 3 monitors.

This I want to achieve using a Powershell script -
Get input list of machine name on csv`enter code here` run the report and see the serial number on it

Earlier we were using vb script that used to work. 
But it doesn't work for some reason now.

Please help me with such Powershell script?

Comment: $ComputerName = 'Station01'   Get-CimInstance -Namespace root\wmi -ClassName wmimonitorid -ComputerName $ComputerName | foreach {
 New-Object -typenam  psobject -Property @{
        Company = ($_.ManufacturerName -notmatch '^0$' | foreach {[char]$_}) -join ""
        Name = ($_.UserFriendlyName -notmatch '^0$' | foreach {[char]$_}) -join ""
        Serial = ($_.SerialNumberID -notmatch '^0$' | foreach {[char]$_}) -join ""
    }
}

Comment: get  machinename from  column1  . that data , get monitor serial,  monitor serial paste on column 3 or 4 incase it has 2 monitors   " i have no idea to write codes i just google it and ready alot but its been 6months i havent figure it out yet

Comment: Why don't you put that code in your comment in the question itself, and [format it](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251361/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)?